# locate displayed element with webdriverio

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver-io

When developing in the Ionic framework, the generated html sometimes will contain duplicate DOM elements, where all but one tree of elements is hidden with a class="ion-page-hidden" at the top level.

When using webdriverio to try and locate an element inside this tree, it find duplicated elements. Since the ion-page-hidden class is at the top of the tree, and not on the element itself, how can we use Xpath to locate only the displayed element.

I couldn't figure out any way to modify the XPath selector with a second condition since the elements are exactly the same!

So instead I have tried to use the webdriverio isDisplayed() function:

```
get openHamburgerMenu()         { return Utils.visibleElement($$("//ion-button[@name='button-open-menu']")); }
```

where the Utils function is:

```
async visibleElement(elementArray) {
    let returnElement;
    elementArray.forEach(element => {
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            returnElement = element;
        }
    });
    return returnElement;
}
```

but **no** elements are passed into the function. In the chrome browser, I can see two that match the xpath //ion-button[@name='button-open-menu']. I need the one not in the ion-page-hidden block!

### tree

The tree looks like this:

app-for-homes[1]/ion-header/ion-toolbar/ion-buttons[1]/ion-button
app-for-homes[2]/ion-header/ion-toolbar/ion-buttons[1]/ion-button

where app-for-homes[2] happens to have the ion-page-hidden class.

I think it should be possible to use ancestors to identify which of the two elements, matching the xpath, does **not** have a 4th level ancestor with that class? But I'm way out of my depth on day one of working with xpaths...

Comment: Could you please add a minimal html example?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Thanks for your interest. While I am definitely not an expert, from my experience, Xpaths seem to be expressed in shorthand using the path notation, rather than by the full html code. It's far more succinct. I managed to figure it out in the end. See answer below. If you wouldn't mind removing your downvote, as I don't feel it would add anything to clutter this question with html for reasons provided.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick and Dirty

The desired outcome can be achieved using this Xpath:

```
//app-for-homes[1]/ion-header/ion-toolbar/ion-buttons/ion-button[@name='button-open-menu']
```

However, this only works where the order in which the elements appears is known.

### Better Answer

When you have exactly 1 element that is not hidden, Xpaths allow you to look at an elements ancestors as far back as you want to identify the presence / or absence of the hidden class. In this case, we start by finding the ancestor app-for-homes which does **not** include the ion-page-hidden class:

```
//app-for-homes[not(contains(@class,'ion-page-hidden'))]
```

and then simply append the remainder of the path to the desired element. Full answer =

```
//app-for-homes[not(contains(@class,'ion-page-hidden'))]/ion-header/ion-toolbar/ion-buttons/ion-button[@name='button-open-menu']
```